# How can i setup load_and_authorize_resource through a habtm association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have tasks which I want to display in project context. They are associated through a habtm association. So I have three tables: `projects, tasks and projects_tasks`.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
  ...

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  ...
```

How can i setup `load_and_authorize_resource` through a habtm association?

```
# ???
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project, :shallow => true
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make you join table a model such that a Project `has_many :tasks, :through => : assignments`

Comment: I will try this, maybe this is the way to go.